# Getting Resources from SherlockFragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-resources

I am trying to get a color from `colors.xml`, using something along the lines of

`view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bgcolor_view));`

Although there is a `R.color.bgcolor_view` in my `colors.xml` file, the `R.color` part only shows colors that are available in the built-in android settings. So I'm assuming that `getResources()` is not getting the resources from my project.

So, my question is, how do I obtain resources from within a SherlockFragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your imports, you probably imported android.R, so remove this import and double check that you import your own R from your own project.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I can't believe I fell for this one again. Thanks!

Comment: don't worry. It happens to the best of us :)